# App pool is stopped on every request to the site

Tags: iis

the Application pool is being stopped on each request to my site which is hosted on IIS 7.5.

in the browser I see error "HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable."

I've looked in the Event Viewer and I saw the following error:
"The Module DLL C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\warmup.dll failed to load.  The data is the error."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. The "AppWarmupModule" was registered in Modules in IIS. I think this happened when I was experimenting with AppWarmup. I opened IIS\Modules, did a Remove of "AppWarmupModule"  in the context menu and the problem went away.

Comment: This was called "ApplicationInitializationModule" on my machine